# Conditional sampling a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, random, sampling

I am a newbie in R and want to perform a specific task but I am lost on the specificities of it and I would really appreciate if someone could help me through it.

**What I would like to do is**: I want to sample, say, 2 random couple on year 2000 including every unique male on that year (e.g. on year 2000, the first random couple sampled is M1-F2, and therefore the second couple must be M2 (the other unique male) - *any female other then F2*). Then, sample another 2 from 2001, but on 2002 I want to sample 3. When the loop finishes to sample across all years I want to store the mean of "Diff_ages" and "Diff_weights". Then repeat this loop 100 times to get a distribution and compare to my real data.

So the conditions are that on each year I want to sample different number of random couples (those numbers are stored in another df, and the male and female should be unique within each year but can vary across years).

I started the code like this: (I know that this only samples twice from year 2000 and can have the same male which I don't want).

```
couples <- data.frame (Male = c("M1","M1","M1","M2","M2","M2","M1","M1","M1","M1","M3","M3","M3","M3","M3","M3","M3","M4","M4","M4","M5","M5","M5"), Female = c("F1","F2","F3","F1","F2","F3","F2","F3","F4","F5","F2","F3","F4","F5","F3","F6","F7","F3","F6","F7","F3","F6","F7"), Year = c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002), Diff_ages = c(0,2,1,3,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,5,4,3,0,1,2,2,3,2,1,0,2), Diff_weights = c(0.20,0.25,0.24,0.34 ,0.21 ,0.24,0.21,0.25,0.26,0.24,0.26,0.23,0.22,0.21,0.18,0.21,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.23,0.28,0.25,0.24))

Nb_true_couples <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002), Nb_true_couples = c(2,3,2))

# Seed for reproducibility
set.seed(2022)

# Number iterations to build null distribution
  n_rep = 100 

# Number of samples to draw for each year
  sample_size = Nb_true_couples

# Vector to store means
  mean_diff_ages = rep(NA,n_rep)
  mean_diff_weights = rep(NA,n_rep)
  
for (i in 1:n_rep){
  random_couples_sample=couples[sample(which(couples$Year == "2000"),size=2,replace=F),]
  
  # Calculate and store the means
  mean_diff_ages[i] = mean(random_couples_sample$Diff_ages)
  mean_diff_weights[i] = mean(random_couples_sample$Diff_weights)
}
```

This is my first question on SO so please be patient with me if I am not doing this in clearer way. If someone can guide me through this I would really appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: This sampling regimen is quite complicated - and there's the possibility of needing to backtrack (one could imagine that after selecting a few couples, you may need more selections but there are no valid choices left).  Are you sure you need to make it this complicated? "Pick one random row for each man for each year" is easy with `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(Male, Year) %>% slice_sample(n = 1)`. But the extra restrictions make it much harder.

Comment: @GregorThomas, thanks for the other editing comment, I think I included the needed info. To be honest I don't know what "backtrack" means. I thought that I couldn't figure this out by myself because I am too much of a novice in R, so I am not aware of the true difficulty of this.

Comment: Like, let's say one year has couple `M1 F1, M1 F2, M2 F2, M2 F3, M3 F3` and you want 2 samples. You first randomly pick M2, and then select the `M2 F3` row. Then you pick `M3`, but there are no eligible M3 rows because F2 has already been chosen, so you have to go back and re-select `M1`. That's a simple example for a simple case, but one could imagine more complex cases where certain early selections mean there are few or even no ways to get enough samples...

Comment: A common workaround for a problem like that would be to set a parameter `n_tries`, where if you can't find a valid sample after `n_tries`, you abort the process. There may not be a valid sample of a certain size, but it can be a tricky problem just to figure that  out if the number of samples is anything close to the number of males and females in the data.

Comment: It's not at all impossible, it can certainly be done. But simpler versions are **so easy**, taking a minute or two to write, it's worth asking the question of why you need a complex process that might take an experienced R user 30 minutes or an hour to write. It seems like you're trying to do some sort of bootstrap estimate of the diff_ages and diff_weights, but it's not at all clear that this complex sampling process would give any better results than a simpler sampling process.

Comment: That is why for every male (in each year) I have all the possible M F combinations, but as soon as a certain female has been chosen, within the R loop it would, indeed, need to go back to the other sampled couples and check whether the female was already picked and, if yes, go to the table with all possible combinations and find a new, unique female. Do you think my logic here is not feasible?

Comment: You are right, I am trying something kind of too difficult for my experience but I am running an experiment of sexual selection in which the dataset is structured like the one I showed and I need to figure this out. I have several tables of different metrics in which each dataset is composed of around 50k rows. To give you a specific number: in year 2000 I have 3105 rows (45M x 69F) and I want to sample 45 couples (one couple for each unique male). All the time I have more F than M.